# How to create date in Google Sheets having YY-MM-DD_HH:MM as string?

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

How to create date in Google sheets having YY-MM-DD_HH:MM as string ?

[STEP I] INPUT:

```
20.01.05_01:00
```

Extracting with REGEXEXTRACT(F1;"(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{2})_(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})") to:

```
20  01  05  01:00
```

[STEP II] CREATE DATE:
I can create date without HH:MM --> =DATE(2000+H1;I1;J1)

```
2020-01-05
```

How to add 01:00 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is in F1:

```
20.01.05_01:00
```

try this formula:

```
=1*SUBSTITUTE(F1;"_";" ")
```

then select the cell and choose Format>Number>Date time.